# Opcache display only a specific directory and sub directory

Tags: php, opcache

On my server I have several domain names. When I list the files via opcache, I saw every opcache files use.

I would know if it's possible to select just a directory and its sub-directory to display the opcache information: for example, `/var/www/test.com/web/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a whitelist unfortunately, but you can blacklist the `php` files you don't want opcache to cache using the `opcache.blacklist_filename` directive:

Documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.blacklist-filename